# SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC Inconsistently Displays

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I've recently decided to dive into writing a C++ game using SDL as one of my libraries. During the course of my program writing and learning about SDL, I stumbled across a peculiar bug in my program, and decided to replicate it in an SSCCE to make sure that I wasn't crazy.

The problem appears to be that when I pass SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC as a flag to SDL_CreateRenderer, I get inconsistent rendering. To compare, I ran the program 50 times with, and 50 times without the flag, and made that the only change to my program in each case. Without the flag, the display worked 100% of the time. With the flag on, it only rendered successfully 13 out of the 50 times.

Here's the program:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Unable to initialize SDL: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    SDL_Window* win = SDL_CreateWindow("Testing", 
                                       SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 
                                       SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                       640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, 
                                                SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | 
                                                SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
    for(int x = 0; x < 640; x+=32)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < 480; y+=32)
        {
            SDL_Rect rect = {x+1, y+1, 31, 31};
            SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);
        }
    }
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    SDL_Delay(500);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

If it makes a difference, I'm compiling and testing the program on Ubuntu 15.04, GCC/G++ 4.9.2, Compiled and linked against SDL 2.0.2.

Being so new to SDL, and still relatively new to both C++ and C (I come from a Java background), I think it's very likely that I've made a simple error that I'm not catching, but I can't think of what I might have done.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. What exactly do you see when it "fails"?

Comment: @keltar When it fails, the window does appear, but the area where it should render is merely a copy of whatever was in the background before the window popped up, which is the same behavior I get when no rendering/drawing is applied.

Comment: What's your graphics driver? Is compositing enabled? What happens if you ask driver to force vsync?

Comment: @keltar I am using my on-board intel graphics card on my laptop. Being a laptop, there are no separately installed graphics cards. lshw shows my driver to be i915. Compositing is enabled, according to compiz. OpenGL is set to sync to VBLANK, by the same tool. Not quite sure how to ask the driver to force vsync. 

Should note that graphics are not (yet) my area of expertise.

Comment: I meant, in your case, setting environment variable `vblank_mode` to `0` (disables vsync) or `1` (forces vsync even if application didn't requested it). Unfortunately I never encountered your problem so can't tell you exact reason or solution, but it's been told to me many times that combination of GPU vsync and compiz vsync is pure madness. I suggest trying it without compositing. In fast-updating application it wouldn't be a problem, but if you only want to draw just one frame - it becomes tricky; probably for some reason your flip happened too early when compiz wasn't ready to get image.

Comment: @keltar I didn't know about the vblank_mode env variable. I set it to 0, and suddenly the problem disappeared, with every run working just fine. Setting it to 1 caused the problem to work as normally (if anything, it took even more tries before I got a successful run. Only 1/12 runs). However, after setting the environment variable, whether it was set to 1 OR 0, each run produced the output "ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment." twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those seeing this question in the future, the problem appears to have resolved itself a little over a year later, as I can no longer replicate my own SSCCE. It may be a change of environment, as I am not using the same system and am now using an Nvidia Graphics Card. The problem, though I can no longer verify this, was almost certainly in the environment or the hardware. That same laptop ended up failing (motherboard issues) a mere month or two later, so take from that what you will. Consider checking your hardware health and attempting a completely clean environment if you are experiencing this same issue.