# SDL Window only renders contents behind it

Tags: opengl, sdl-2, freepascal, lazarus

I have the following Pascal code, using the standard SDL2 libraries. All of the code is valid, the image is in the proper directory, and on very rare occasions the desired image will load. A solid 99% of the time, however, it shows nothing but a static picture of the window contents behind it.

```
program project1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

uses
    {$IFDEF UNIX}{$IFDEF UseCThreads}
    cthreads,
    {$ENDIF}{$ENDIF}
    Classes, sysutils, SDL2, SDL2_image
    { you can add units after this };

const
  SWIDTH = 709;
  SHEIGHT = 488;
var
  Window: PSDL_Window;
  ScreenSurface, Symbol: PSDL_Surface;
begin
  WriteLn(GetCurrentDir);
  if SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0 then halt;
  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
  Window:= SDL_CreateWindow('Symbol Test', SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SWIDTH, SHEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    ScreenSurface:= SDL_GetWindowSurface(Window);
  IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);
    Symbol:= IMG_Load('symbol.png');
  SDL_BlitSurface(Symbol, nil, ScreenSurface, nil);
  SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(Window);
  SDL_Delay(5000);
    SDL_FreeSurface(Symbol);
  SDL_FreeSurface(ScreenSurface);

  SDL_DestroyWindow(Window);
  SDL_Quit();
end.
```

Comment: Probably vsync-related. Try either displaying multiple times in loop until 5 seconds passes, or disable acceleration ([SDL_HINT_FRAMEBUFFER_ACCELERATION](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_HINT_FRAMEBUFFER_ACCELERATION)). Also you shouldn't free `ScreenSurface`, but it is unrelated to your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500491/sdl-renderer-presentvsync-inconsistently-displays may be helpful if you're on conpositing-enabled OS/WM, although it provides no clear solution.

Comment: @keltar: Fantastic! You're correct, it was an issue with VSync. I've fixed it now, and updating inside of a polling event loop was all I had to do. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to keltar in the comments for pointing out that this was a VSync related error. By shifting the update process to be done from inside an event queue as opposed to statically once before a delay, everything works normally. Here's the updated code for reference:

```
program project1;

{$mode tp}{$H+}

uses
    {$IFDEF UNIX}{$IFDEF UseCThreads}
    cthreads,
    {$ENDIF}{$ENDIF}
    Classes, sysutils, SDL2, SDL2_image
    { you can add units after this };

const
  SWIDTH = 709;
  SHEIGHT = 488;
var
  Window: PSDL_Window;
  ScreenSurface, Symbol: PSDL_Surface;
  e: TSDL_Event;
begin
  WriteLn(GetCurrentDir);
  if SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0 then halt;
  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
  Window:= SDL_CreateWindow('Symbol Test', SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SWIDTH, SHEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    ScreenSurface:= SDL_GetWindowSurface(Window);
  IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);
    Symbol:= IMG_Load('symbol.png');
  SDL_BlitSurface(Symbol, nil, ScreenSurface, nil);
  while true do
  begin
    while SDL_PollEvent(@e) <> 0 do
    begin
      if e.type_ = SDL_KEYDOWN then WriteLn(e.key.keysym.scancode);
      SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(Window);
    end;
  end;

  SDL_DestroyWindow(Window);
  SDL_Quit();
end.
```